# Slow Queries and how to optimize a function php code

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This query is to search for keywords in job posts using Wordpress. This code gets my queries so slow and Im stuck. I have over 40 000 posts but whenever Is search for something, the results shows up in a few seconds (3-5 seconds).

Any ideas are welcome.

```
function get_job_listings_keyword_search( $args ) {
        global $wpdb, $job_manager_keyword;

        $conditions   = array();
        $conditions[] = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '%" . esc_sql( $job_manager_keyword ) . "%'";
        $conditions[] = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID IN ( SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_value LIKE '%" . esc_sql( $job_manager_keyword ) . "%' )";


        $args['where'] .= " AND ( " . implode( ' OR ', $conditions ) . " ) "; 

        return $args;
```

Comment: "LIKE" can be pretty slow, particularly when you have a pattern with a wildcard at both the start and end. Is it possible to refactor the query to remove the like, or at least one of the wildcard?

Comment: You need to post theresults of explain for a few queries. Some sample data, exact queries and expected results would not come amiss either.

Comment: I need to use LIKE so it search for everything in the content. I removed the post.tile function. Any other ways?

Comment: Do you have an index on you searched columns? See this one: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html

Comment: Yes @tillz i have index on the columns.

Comment: could you post an example of the query? (with example values) and the [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)-output of this query?

Comment: @tillz 
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS jobbgo_posts.ID
FROM jobbgo_posts
WHERE 1 =1
AND jobbgo_posts.post_type =  'job_listing'
AND (
(
jobbgo_posts.post_status =  'publish'
)
)
AND (
jobbgo_posts.ID
IN (

SELECT post_id
FROM jobbgo_postmeta
WHERE meta_value LIKE  '%person%'
)
)
ORDER BY jobbgo_posts.menu_order ASC , jobbgo_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10`

Comment: You are not going to optimize this more, do what you want, `LIKE` comprisons is way much slower than other comparisons

Comment: @PieterGoosen Whats the better choice here then?